# Trying to update a table - Error: Unhandled promise rejection node.js

Tags: node.js, unhandled-exception

I'm trying to update a user with a hashed password when I start the app.
So I wrote this in **app.js**:

```
try {
  bcrypt.hash("ADMIN", saltRounds, async function(err, hash) {
    queryUpdate = await Utilisateur.query().patch({
        MOTPASS: hash
    }).where('NOGENE', 4219)
    .catch(console.log('err'));
 });
} catch (err) {
  errorDbHandler.sendErrorHttp(err, res);
}
```

And I got this error:

```
(node:6800) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Utilisateur.query is not a function
    at D:\Project\***\backend\app.js:48:37
(node:6800) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6800) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Insufficient details, What is Utilisateur? Please provide more details.

Comment: You will need to specify what "Utilisateur" is exactly. It appears to be some sort of model in an ORM but it's still not clear what database or ORM you're using.

Answer (score 0):

use this code for catching the error:

```
try {
  bcrypt.hash("ADMIN", saltRounds, async function(err, hash) {
    try {
      queryUpdate = await Utilisateur.query().patch({
        MOTPASS: hash
      }).where('NOGENE', 4219);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
 });
} catch (err) {
  errorDbHandler.sendErrorHttp(err, res);
}
```

you tried to mix "then().catch()" with "await", which will not work.

Comment: It works, I got no longer that error, but I got this error : TypeError: Utilisateur.query is not a function.. Any idea?

Comment: looks like there is something wrong with your dependencies/includes. Like the others commented: please show your code on how you include the db script, so we can see what module and how you are using it.